Build time error when using Redis inside Next.js
I use Redis in my Next.js project. It works good but it seems in build time (next build) it tries to connect to Redis and since Redis connection is not available it throws this error:
Collecting page data  ..[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)

My Redis singleton client is:
import Redis from 'ioredis';

export const redis: Redis =
  global.redis ||
  new Redis({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: Number.parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT ?? '6379', 10),
    db: Number.parseInt(process.env.REDIS_DB ?? '6', 10),
    keyPrefix: process.env.REDIS_PREFIX ?? ''
  });

/** This prevents creating multiple instance of redis client in development mode */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  global.redis = redis;
}

As Redis connection shouldn't be used in build time. How can I fix this?

Ok, if you have the same problem and running pnpm build complains about having Redis connection errors, wrapping the Redis client in a function solves the problem. I changed the code to the following and imported the function instead of const in other files:
import Redis from 'ioredis';
export function getRedisClient(): Redis {
  const redis =
    global.redis ||
    new Redis({
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'localhost',
      port: Number.parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT ?? '6379', 10),
      db: Number.parseInt(process.env.REDIS_DB ?? '6', 10),
      keyPrefix: process.env.REDIS_PREFIX ?? ''
    });
  /** This prevents creating multiple instance of redis client in development mode */
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    global.redis = redis;
  }

  return redis;
}

